# Lucene calculate average term frequency

Tags: solr, lucene, similarity, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I am currently implementing a modification of Lucene's standard [BM25 similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html), based on the following [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280599788_Verboseness_Fission_for_BM25_Document_Length_Normalization?ev=prf_pub). The implementation of the actual formula is straightforward, but I am struggling with the computation of the necessary statistics.

I need the following two statistics:

- **Average term frequency** of a document:
  `length of document / # unique terms of the document`, (i.e. an indicator of the repetitiveness of a document - for a document with no repetitions this would be 1, with each term occuring twice it would be 2 and so on)
- **Mean average term frequency**: This is the arithmetic mean of the above measure over all documents of the collection. This can be seen as the average repetitiveness of the whole corpus.

I found out, that I can calculate the per-document average term frequency at indexing time by overriding the `computeNorm` method of my Similarity implementation. I can store the value alongside the norm value by bit-operations (not exceptionally pretty, but so far it works). At query-time I can then extract the document's average term frequency and length.

However, this does not help finding the mean average term frequency. It is obviously a collection-wide value and should therefore be computed in [Similarity.computeWeight](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html#computeWeight-float-org.apache.lucene.search.CollectionStatistics-org.apache.lucene.search.TermStatistics...-) as far as I understand, but I don't see how this could be done given the arguments of the function.

**Which would be the ideal place for calculating these statistics?**

I am new to Lucene, so it may be that there is an obvious solution which I did not yet see. I am grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0):

`Similarity.computeWeight` method have `CollectionStatistics` param, which contains `maxDoc` (returns the total number of documents, regardless of whether they all contain values for this field), and `TermStatistics`, which contains `term` and `totalTermFreq` (returns the total number of occurrences of this term) and by dividing it you could get mean term frequency

Comment: why total term freq divided by total number of docs didn't give you an average?

Comment: I didn't get your formula though, could you explain it in the original post?

Comment: I don't think that this matches what I need.  I need `1/|D| * sum for d ∈ D (L_d / |T_d| )`, i.e. how many duplicate words a document has on average. You proposed something different - it may be also called mean term frequency but not in the sense of the paper I am talking about. (Sry for this mess - unfortunately I am not yet allowed to post formulas as images, else the formulas would look nicer)

Comment: "total term freq divided by total number of docs" gives me an average, but not the one I search. I tried to explain it better now in the comment above and the original question

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate your own "norm" to stick in Lucene's index. Basically, you can store additional features to use in your scoring using NumericDocValuesField.

This means, at index time, you'll want to tokenize your text yourself. I have some example code, (in Kotlin, but happy to answer follow-up questions if you prefer Java)

Tokenize based on any Lucene analyzer: (Expressed as a Kotlin extension function, just imagine that `this` is the first argument to this static method as an Analyzer if you're more comfortable in Java.

```
fun Analyzer.tokenize(field: String, input: String): List<String> {
    val tokens = arrayListOf<String>()
    this.tokenStream(field, input).use { body ->
        val charTermAttr = body.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute::class.java)

        // iterate over tokenized field:
        body.reset()
        while(body.incrementToken()) {
            tokens.add(charTermAttr.toString())
        }
    }
    return tokens
}
```

Then you take the tokenized text, and calculate the information you need based on it. The code I'm using wants them separate, but something like this should get you going.

```
    fun setTextField(field: String, text: String, terms: List<String>): List<IndexableField> {
        val length = terms.size
        val uniqLength = terms.toSet().size

        val keep = ArrayList<IndexableField>()
        keep.add(TextField(field, text, Field.Store.YES))
        keep.add(NumericDocValuesField("lengths:$field", length.toLong()))
        keep.add(NumericDocValuesField("unique:$field", uniqLength.toLong()))
        return keep
    }
```

This is a per-document statistic, so you can keep track of the mean while indexing and store it separately from Lucene, i.e. I usually create a "meta.json" near the index for these kinds of things.

I'm not familiar with SOLR, per-se, but when you go to implement a Weight subclass in Lucene, you have access to these numeric doc values as follows:

```
class SpecialBM25(...) : Weight(...) {
    ...
    override fun scorer(context: LeafReaderContext): Scorer {
        val uniq = context.reader().getNumericDocValues("unique:$field")
        val lengths = context.reader().getNumericDocValues("lengths:$field")
        ... generate Scorer and give it your additional features ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really nice. I already saw that I can retrieve numericDocValues but had no idea how to compute them. The only thing I am still missing is the mean average term frequency (i.e. the collection-wide value). It is the mean of all per-document `length / uniqLength`. Do you have a suggestion where to compute this value in your approach?

Comment: I would fiddle with the ``setTextField`` method to take a document, and add the fields to it, and return the ``length/uniqLength`` as a ``double``. Then, in your loop over indexing documents, keep track of the ``sumLengthRatio``, and the ``totalNumDocuments``, and then divide them when you want the mean. Lucene doesn't have a good place to store it, but you could throw in a "magic" document for this statistic, i.e. a document with a special ID and a ``StoredField("lengthRatioMean", sumLengthRatio/totalNumDocuments)``.